# Only match first two occurences in regex - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace text with a link. The regex I now have, replaces all matches but I only want to replace the first two occurrences.

It should replace all occurrences of `find me` with a link, except when it is located in a  or  tag.

https://regex101.com/r/6R2ydW/1
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/nLI

My current regex:

```
/<(a|h[1-6])[^>]*>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\-\.,]|(?:<(.*)>.*<\/\1>))*<\/(a|h[1-6])>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(Find Me)\b(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/ig
```

My dummy content:

```
Lorem ipsum find me and skip when 
<b>find me</b> is inside a link tag 
like this find me
<h1>find me in the title</h1>
<a href="#">here you can find me too</a>.
<h2 class="heading">Lorem Ipsum dolor find me here too</h2>
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell 1 a</td><td>Find me</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 2 with find me</td><td><a href="#foo">Find me</a></td></tr>
</table>
<h3 class="heading">Duomo Di find me San Martino</h3>
<p>FIND ME as well</p>
```

My PHP preg_replace:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum find me and skip when 
    <b>find me</b> is inside a link tag 
    like this find me
    <h1>find me in the title</h1>
    <a href="#">here you can find me too</a>.
    <h2 class="heading">Lorem Ipsum dolor find me here too</h2>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Cell 1 a</td><td>Find me</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 2 with find me</td><td><a href="#foo">Find me</a></td></tr>
    </table>
    <h3 class="heading">Duomo Di find me San Martino</h3>
    <p>FIND ME as well</p>';

$regex = "/<(a|h[1-6])[^>]*>(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\-\.,]|(?:<(.*)>.*<\/\1>))*<\/(a|h[1-6])>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(" . preg_quote('find me') . ")\b(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))/i";

$text = preg_replace($regex, sprintf('<a href="%s">$4</a>', 'http://example.com'), $text);
```

Hope a fellow programmer can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the (for me) unknown `$limit` parameter .

`$text = preg_replace($regex, sprintf('<a href="%s">$4</a>', 'http://example.com'), $text, $limit = 2);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php